# c++ program quits when i input something or try to read something?

Tags: c++

Any help would be greatly appreciated, my program quits as soon as i come out of the menu and try to enter something, been racking my brains trying to figure this out and is very annoying as i cant get anything else done until i fix this problem. i am a bit of a begginer at c++ so dont slate me if its a rookie mistake please haha!

This is the source code, its not yet a completed program just cant figure out whats wrong just now.

Thanks for any help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct cust
{
    int employeeno, deptno;
    char fname[10], sname[10], weekend[10];
    float hours, othours, rate, otrate, normalpay, otpay, grosspay, netpay, totalni, totaltax, ni, tax;

};

int Menu(int& menuchoice);
void InputRecords(cust c[], int row, int menuchoice);
int Calculations(cust c[]);

int SearchNumber(cust c[], int &row);
int DeleteRecords();
int TotalPay();

int main()
{
    struct cust c[100];

    int menuchoice, row;

    Menu(menuchoice);

    if (menuchoice == 1){
    system("CLS");
    InputRecords(c, row, menuchoice);
    }

    if (menuchoice == 2){
    system("CLS");
    SearchNumber(c, row);
    }

    if (menuchoice == 3){
    system("CLS");
    DeleteRecords();
    }

    if (menuchoice == 4){
    system("CLS");

    }

    if (menuchoice == 5){
    system("CLS");
    exit(5);
    }

    //Calculations(cust c[]);

}

int Menu(int& menuchoice){

    cout << " \n\n\n\n\n                             1. Input a Payslip" << endl << endl;;
    cout << "                             2. Read a Payslip " << endl << endl;
    cout << "                             3.              " << endl << endl;
    cout << "                             4.              " << endl << endl;
    cout << "                             5. Quit the Program" << endl << endl;
    cin >> menuchoice;

}



void InputRecords(cust c[], int row, int menuchoice){

    char another;

    do{
    cout << "Please Enter Their Employee Number: " << endl;
    cin >> c[row].employeeno;

    cout << "Please Enter Their First Name: " << endl;
    cin >> c[row].fname,9;

    cout << "Please Enter Their Second Name: " << endl;
    cin >> c[row].sname,9;

    cout << "Please Enter Their Department Number 1 - 9: " << endl;
    cin >> c[row].deptno;

    cout << "Please Enter The Hours They Have Worked: " << endl;
    cin >> c[row].hours;

        if (c[row].hours >= 37.5){

            cout << "Please Enter Any Overtime They Have Worked: " << endl;
            cin >> c[row].othours;
        }

    cout << "Please Enter Their Rate of Pay: " << endl;
    cin >> c[row].rate;

    cout << "Please Enter The Date of the Week End (DD/MM/YYYY): " << endl;
    cin >> c[row].weekend, 9;

    row++;

    cout << endl;

    //Putting it in the file.
    ofstream timesheetFile("Timesheet.txt", ios::app);

    if(timesheetFile.is_open()){
        cout << "File has been opened." << endl;

        timesheetFile << c[row].employeeno << "    " << c[row].fname << "    "  << c[row].sname << "    "  << c[row].deptno << "  " << c[row].hours << "  " <<  c[row].othours << "   " << c[row].rate << "  " << c[row].weekend << "\n" << endl;

        timesheetFile.close();
    }else{
        cout << "Error! File is not open." << endl;
    }

    cout << "Would you like to enter another record? Y/N : ";
    cin >> another;

    cout << endl << endl;

    }while(row<100 && another == 'y');

    system("CLS");
    main();
}

//read records
int SearchNumber(cust c[], int &row){

    //system("CLS");

    int empno;

    cout << "Enter Employee Number : ";

    cin >> empno;

    for (int i=0; i < row; i++)
    {
        if (empno == c[i].employeeno){

            system("CLS");
            cout << c[i].employeeno << endl << c[i].fname << c[i].sname << endl;
        }
    }
}

//deleterecords
int DeleteRecords(){

}

//calculations
int Calculations(float normalpay, float& hours, float& rate, float otpay, float otrate, float& othours, float grosspay, float tax, float ni, float netpay, float totalni, float totaltax){

    ni = 6.8 / 100;
    tax = 12.75 / 100;
    otrate = 1.5 * rate;

    normalpay = hours * rate ;
    otpay = otrate * othours;

    grosspay = normalpay + otpay;

    totalni = grosspay * ni;

    totaltax = tax * grosspay;

    netpay = normalpay + otpay - totaltax - totalni;

//    cout << totaltax << endl;
//
//    cout << totalni << endl;
//
//    cout << netpay << endl;


}

int TotalPay(){




}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to give your thoughts why it happens... did you ever try to use a debugger to see what problem is? Looking in your code I can see at least two mistakes and obviously an answer why it's quitting - because that's how it done.. =)

Comment: Recursive call to `main()` from `InputRecords()` is probably not what you really want to do.

Comment: where are the return values for those functoins??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - you'll get a badge (c:

Comment: Get rid of half the code, then again, then again, until it doesn't crash. Then add back half the remaining. If it crashes, remove half the half you added, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here

```
int main()
{
    struct cust c[100];

    int menuchoice, row;

    Menu(menuchoice);

    if (menuchoice == 1){
        system("CLS");
        InputRecords(c, row, menuchoice);
    }
```

You have not given the variable `row` a value but you use `row` when you call `InputRecords`.

From a look at your code it seems to me that the row variable should be moved to the InputRecords function and initalised to zero there. I can't see why you have the row variable in the main function.

Also I can't see why you pass menuchoice to InputRecords, it doesn't get used there. It all seems a bit random, maybe you should review functions and parameter passing.

Comment: i need to use row elsewhere but ive not finished the program, i didn't see why i passed menuchoice either but it only worked if i did so i didn't question it, thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `row` variable is never being initialized. Why is this?

It's also good practice to initialize your variables like `menuchoice`

Comment: wow that was pretty rookie, cant believe i was stuck on it for that long, thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 int Menu(int& menuchoice);
 void InputRecords(cust c[], int row, int menuchoice);// declared
 int Calculations(cust c[]);

 int SearchNumber(cust c[], int &row);
 int DeleteRecords();
 int TotalPay();

 int main()
 {
     struct cust c[100];

     int menuchoice, row; // declared again but never initialized

     Menu(menuchoice);

     if (menuchoice == 1){ 
     system("CLS");
     InputRecords(c, row, menuchoice); // used
```